# Linux won't load my images for my game

Tags: c++, image, g++

I am using C++ and using the G++ compiler to compile my game. It compiles fine, but I'm linking to images, and they aren't showing up in-game. I tried using local links and full links but I couldn't get either one to work. Is there a special way to link to a file in Linux?

Code Example:

```
StatBack.load_image("\\Dropbox\\Pirate_Entertainment\\images\\hud_thumbnails\\backdrop.png");
StatBack.apply_image_surface(nCurrentX - 180,nCurrentY-230,0);
StatBack.v_DeleteImages();
```

Comment: What is the path to your image and can you find it with ls (\\ is not the path separator in Unix)

Comment: Not only is the path separator `/`, but if you put a leading `/` I believe it will point to the root of the file system.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I looked all over google to see if Unix did file paths different and no one had any help. Windows uses \ in path names, so I was confused

Comment: Windows will accept `/` just fine in API calls. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx (About halfway down).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using some kind of portability wrapper which transforms your backslashes to forward slashes, you probably want to use forward slashes:

```
StatBack.load_image("/Dropbox/Pirate_Entertainment/images/hud_thumbnails/backdrop.png");
```

or, more likely, using a relative path:

```
StatBack.load_image("Dropbox/Pirate_Entertainment/images/hud_thumbnails/backdrop.png");
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact it is safe to use a forward slash in windows as well. The ANSI C standard allows forward slashes to be used in file names as the path separator.

Comment: OK, great!

my programming teacher just taught me to use the '\\' so I'm used to it

Answer (score 0):

you should use / as a path separator instead of \ (that C++ reduces to ).

Comment: thanks bro, some people on here don't know how to help out...

I'm just so used to Visual Studios and windows that I used the '\\' to do directories

Comment: I think that Visual C runtime accepts / as path separator, so your code should be almost portable. Don't know about cygwin, so I avoided hinting in the answer.